# Maclaurin series of $\ln(1-x+x^2)$

Tags: calculus

Is there a closed form expression for $\text{n}^{\text{th}}$ coefficient of Maclaurin series of
 $$\ln(1-x+x^2)$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $\ln(1-x+x^2)=\ln\left(\dfrac{1+x^3}{1+x}\right)$

Use (two times!) the expansion of $\ln(1+t)$ to conclude!

Hoping this helped,

Comment: I want to say a "Big Thanks" to you for this hint!

Comment: @MartinGales: Glad it helped!